# How to type a parameter pointed to a C structure of a C function in Swift code?

Tags: c, swift

I am trying to use CLIPS with swift and, a priori, the communication between Swift and C is natural or, at least, quite direct. The thing is that I don't know very well how to convert to the necessary type of theCV parameter of the Eval function. Does anyone has experience with these scams and help me?

I put the code that I try to run.

```
/*
===========================================================
These are the definitions of the structures and prototypes.
===========================================================

typedef struct clipsValue CLIPSValue;
struct clipsValue {
    union {
        ...
        TypeHeader *header;
        CLIPSLexeme *lexemeValue;
        ...
    };
};

typedef struct fact Fact;
struct fact {
    union {
        ...
        TypeHeader header;
    };
    ...
};
    
EvalError Eval(Environment *theEnv, const char *theString, CLIPSValue *returnValue);
*/


import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var clipsEnv = CreateEnvironment();
    
    @State private var message: String = ""
    @State private var theCV = CLIPSValue.self  // I am not sure about this assignment...
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            Build(clipsEnv, "(deftemplate message (slot value))")
            Build(clipsEnv, "(defrule goodbye => (assert (message (value \"Fact Slot Retrieval\"))))")
            
            Eval(clipsEnv, "(reset)", nil)
            Eval(clipsEnv, "(run)", nil)
            
            //--------------------------------------------------------------
            // How do I map the variable theCV of the Eval function?
            //--------------------------------------------------------------
            Eval(clipsEnv, "(find-all-facts ((?f message)) TRUE)", &theCV)
            
            //ERROR in &theCV:
            //Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<CLIPSValue.Type>' 
            //(aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<clipsValue.Type>') to expected argument 
            //type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<CLIPSValue>' (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<clipsValue>')
            
            if (theCV.header->type == MULTIFIELD_TYPE)
            {
                //...
            }
                        
        }, label: {
            Text("Call C Func")
        }).padding()
        
        Text("\(self.message)")
    }
}
```

I need to collect the value of theCV parameter to parse its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare a local `var`, and pass that to `Eval`.

```
// in the Button() { ... } closure
var theCV = CLIPSValue()
Eval(clipsEnv, "(find-all-facts ((?f message)) TRUE)", &theCV)
```

You don't need a `@State` here unless you also want to use `theCV` in other parts of the view. In that case, you can declare a `@State` of type `CLIPSValue?`.

```
@State var theCV: CLIPSValue?
```

Then assign to this after `Eval`:

```
var theCV = CLIPSValue()
Eval(clipsEnv, "(find-all-facts ((?f message)) TRUE)", &theCV)
self.theCV = theCV
```

Comment: Yes! This works and I have already managed to send the message generated in CLIPS to the iOS interface with SwiftUI. Thank you very much for the suggestion. We continue...